# Web Service Request: Error in Katalon but Working in Postman

Tags: ui-automation, katalon-studio

I'm using Katalon 6.3.2 64-bit and I'm having an issue with connection denied when send a request on my end.

error shown in katalon

[image: snap]

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.RestfulClient.sendRequest(RestfulClient.java:91)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.common.RestfulClient.send(RestfulClient.java:59)
    at com.kms.katalon.controller.WebServiceController.sendRequest(WebServiceController.java:121)
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.webservice.parts.RestServicePart$6.run(RestServicePart.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

Same request being send through Postman and it's working perfectly. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: What are your proxy settings?

Comment: I dont setup any proxy in Katalon Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your client node's firewall settings.

Better yet, try to hit a simple end-point using a simple client code. If you have the same error, it is most likely the firewall issue.

Comment: Hi Edward, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to hit the same endpoint using Postman and it's working. The problem happen to Katalon Studio only. I'm not sure about client node's firewall setting. How to check on that?

Comment: My doubt is that java.exe (or java if you are in *nix) the Katalon studio is using cannot hit the server as the client firewall is blocking it. Postman is a different executable program so firewall won't block it.

Comment: I just tried to use different JRE folder to execute the request but still getting the same error. By default it will use Katalon JRE folder. Change to different JRE folder also not working. This only happen in Katalon GUI. It works fine when the request being sent through script.

Comment: You're correct! Once the application has been white-listed by our internal team, it works fine now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue related to < https://forum.katalon.com/t/5-9-0-getting-a-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-after-update/14500/24> if yes you can find a solution here

Comment: I dont have that option in latest katalon version.